# Custom Formatting for disaplaying amount in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, currency-formatting

I want to display amount/currency in indian format for i.e.122,030,000 as "12,20,30,000.00". I tried this to resolve using custom format in expression like ##,##,##,##0.00, but it doesn't work. because if i have small value for amount like 25000 i get it in ",,25,000" such format. can anyone help me with this? (i want to use this expression in ssrs)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use code to make a string with your special format.

You need to create a loop and check your number to calculate where to put the commas.

Something like:

```
FUNCTION iMONEY(ByVal MONEY AS STRING) AS STRING 'by Bryan

    DIM CHECK AS INTEGER 
    DIM SEPARATE AS BOOLEAN 

    CHECK = INSTR(MONEY, ".") 

    IF CHECK > 0 THEN 
        iMONEY = MID(MONEY, CHECK, LEN(MONEY))
        MONEY = LEFT(MONEY, CHECK - 1)
    END IF


    FOR CHECK  = LEN(MONEY) TO 1 STEP -1

        iMONEY = MID(MONEY, CHECK, 1) & iMONEY 
        IF SEPARATE AND CHECK <> 1 THEN iMONEY = "," & iMONEY
        SEPARATE = NOT SEPARATE

    NEXT CHECK 

END FUNCTION
```

And call it like:

```
=CODE.iMONEY("1234567.8901")

=CODE.iMONEY(Fields!YourField.Value)
```

And you'll get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally the report server uses the format that it has for its regional/culture settings but you can change this to use the user's regional/culture settings.

On the report properties, in the Language property set it to:

```
=User!Language
```

Then use the [standard globalisation formatting codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688127.aspx#enh) throughout your report in the `Format` property. In your example, `C2` will give you the appropriate currency format in the way the user expects to see it. Assuming the user has their culture set appropriately this should be all you need to do.